# Can huge panel sizes be avoided when using ggplotly and facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, ggplotly

Is there a simple way to avoid huge panel sizes when using ggplotly in combinatoin with facet_wrap?
Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dia = ggplot2::diamonds %>% filter(cut=="Ideal", clarity=="SI2", color!="J")

p <- ggplot(data=dia,aes(x=carat, y=price)) 
p <- p + facet_wrap(~color,ncol=1) 
p <- p + geom_point()
p

ggplotly(p)
```

Many thanks in advance.